# Can't ssh into my Mac at home, from office

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, rsa

I'm trying to ssh/sftp to my Mac at home, from office.

I can ping it fine. I'm pretty sure I set up keys correctly with `ssh-keygen`

Here's what I'm getting (private info masked with `•••`):

```
Edit07:.ssh zeev$ ssh -vvv dzg@•••.dyndns.tv
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to •••.dyndns.tv [76.•••.62] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/zeev/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: `secure.log` shows `Jul 11 12:34:31 MacPro sshd[96484]: error: BSM audit: getaddrinfo failed for UNKNOWN: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Jul 11 12:34:31 MacPro sshd[96484]: Could not write ident string to UNKNOWN`

Comment: The message in line 8 says all: `not a rsa1 keyfile`. Have you converted it to ppk-format?

Comment: @ott Not that I know of ... and I just generated the keys locally.

Comment: Do you remember the options to ssh-keygen you've used?

Comment: I did 3 -- rsa, rsa1, and dsa

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong version of your SSH key.

Assuming you're running Mac OS X at work (or any other UNIX/Linux variant) run the following: `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and specify `~/.ssh/home` as your path - this will allow you to use your default `id_rsa` key for work purposes should you need to. Then: `cat ~/.ssh/home.pub` and paste the key into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on your home Mac.

If you're running Windows, use PuTTYgen to regenerate your key, but this time copy the 'OpenSSH' public key (in the scrollable window at the top) into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on your home Mac. Then load the PPK version of your key into PuTTY's agent.